# check tables exceeding certain values and count number of times exceed respective threshold by respective id and label

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe df

```
df <- data.frame(id =c(1,2,1,4,1,5,6),
                    label=c("a","b", "a", "a","a", "e", "a"), 
                    color = c("g","a","g","g","a","a","a"),
                    threshold = c(12, 10, 12, 12, 12, 35, 40),
                    value =c(32.1,0,15.0,10,1,50,45),stringsAsFactors = F
            )
```

[image]

Threshold value is based on the label

I should get a table below like this by considering each id,with respective label how many times exceeding its threshold by the value

Color is independent in consideration for calculating the exceed values

[image]

I tried like this

```
final_df <- df %>% 
  mutate(check = if_else(value > threshold, 1, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(id, label) %>% 
  summarise(exceed = sum(check))
```

But instead of getting with respective id i have got the number of total in exceed

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With base R only, use `aggregate`.

```
aggregate(seq.int(nrow(df)) ~ id + label, df, function(i) sum(df[i, 4] < df[i, 5]))
#  id label seq.int(nrow(df))
#1  1     a                 2
#2  4     a                 0
#3  6     a                 1
#4  2     b                 0
#5  5     e                 1
```

In order to match the expected output posted in the question, it will take a little extra work.

```
exceed <- seq.int(nrow(df))
agg <- aggregate(exceed ~ id + label, df, function(i) sum(df[i, 4] < df[i, 5]))
res <- merge(df[1:3], agg)
unique(res)
#  id label color exceed
#1  1     a     g      2
#3  1     a     a      2
#4  2     b     a      0
#5  4     a     g      0
#6  5     e     a      1
#7  6     a     a      1
```

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Yes, it is. I'm feeling a bit stupid right now.

Answer (score 2):

By a small modification of your code:

```
df %>% 
 group_by(id, label) %>% 
 mutate(check = if_else(value > threshold, 1, 0)) %>% 
 summarise(exceed = sum(check)) %>% 
 group_by(id, label)

     id label exceed
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 a          2
2     2 b          0
3     4 a          0
4     5 e          1
5     6 a          1
```

To match the expected output more closely:

```
df %>% 
 group_by(id, label) %>% 
 mutate(exceed = sum(if_else(value > threshold, 1, 0))) %>% 
 group_by(id, label, color) %>% 
 filter(row_number() == 1)


     id label color threshold value exceed
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 a     g            12  32.1      2
2     2 b     a            10   0        0
3     4 a     g            12  10        0
4     1 a     a            12   1        2
5     5 e     a            35  50        1
6     6 a     a            40  45        1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id, label) %>% 
  mutate(exceed = sum(value > threshold)) %>%
  slice(1)

     id label color threshold value exceed
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
1     1 a     g            12  32.1      2
2     2 b     a            10   0        0
3     4 a     g            12  10        0
4     5 e     a            35  50        1
5     6 a     a            40  45        1
```

If you like the output to contain a separate row for each combination, of ID, label and color, just add a new `group_by` before the `slice` function:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id, label) %>% 
  mutate(exceed = sum(value > threshold)) %>% 
  group_by(id, label, color) %>% 
  slice(1)

     id label color threshold value exceed
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
1     1 a     a            12   1        2
2     1 a     g            12  32.1      2
3     2 b     a            10   0        0
4     4 a     g            12  10        0
5     5 e     a            35  50        1
6     6 a     a            40  45        1
```

Answer (score 0):

A little change in your code

```
final_df <- df %>% mutate(check = if_else(value > threshold, 1, 0)) %>% group_by(id, label) %>% filter(check==1)
unique(final_df$id)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `table` and `merge` :

```
table_ <- table(subset(df,value>threshold, c("id","label")))
df2 <- merge(unique(df[c("id","label","color")]),table_,all.x=TRUE)
df2$Freq[is.na(df2$Freq)] <- 0

#   id label color Freq
# 1  1     a     g    2
# 2  1     a     a    2
# 3  2     b     a    0
# 4  4     a     g    0
# 5  5     e     a    1
# 6  6     a     a    1
```